# Changes a word in a file that you don't know using java

Tags: java, readfile

**Backstory:**

I am creating a *LTspice* program, where I am creating a circuit with over 1000 resistors.

There are 9 different types resistors. I need to change the value of each type of resistor, many times. I can do this manually but I don’t want to. The file is like a text file and can be read by a program like notepad. The filetype is .asc

I was going to create a java program to help me with this.

File Snippet:

```
SYMATTR InstName RiMC3
SYMATTR Value 0.01
SYMBOL res -1952 480 R90
WINDOW 0 0 56 VBottom 2
WINDOW 3 32 56 VTop 2
SYMATTR InstName RiMA3
SYMATTR Value 0.01
SYMBOL res -2336 160 R0
SYMATTR InstName ReC3
SYMATTR Value 8
```

Question:
How can I changes a word, I don´t know, in a file, but I know where it is, compared to another word I know?

An example:
I know the word "RiMC3", I need to changes the 3th word after this word to "0.02".
In the file Snippet the value is "0.01", but this will not always be the case.

My Solution:
I need a place to start.
Is this call something special? I have not found anything like this on google.

Comment: You can try search/replace with regular expressions using any decent text editor (like Notepad++, for example).

Comment: It occurs to me that maybe you don't necessarily need to do this in Java, in which case, any good text editor or text-processing language will do. Perl, sed/awk, and even plain-old shell text filters will work, too. Is this a question about modifying this text once or twice for a project, or do you need a general-purpose solution for a program you are writing?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this programmatically, you need to think about the limitations and requirements.

We don't know exactly how you want to do this, or in what context. But you can write this out on paper, in English, to give you a place to start.

For example, if we are going to make a standalone Java program (or class) to do this, and given simple line-oriented text, a naive approach might be:

- Open the file for read
- Open a file for write
- Scan the file line by line

For each line:

- Match the pattern or regular expression you are looking for and, if
  it matches, modify the line in memory
- Write out the possibly modified line to the output file

Finish up:

- Close the files
- Rename the output file to the input file

Buffering, error handling, application domain specifics are left as an exercise for the reader.